# How do I call Dajax / Dajaxice functions from my Django template

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, dajaxice

I am writing a simple Django application and wish to add ajax paging using Dajax / Dajaxice.  I have started by trying to implement the simple paging example from the Dajax website (http://dajaxproject.com/pagination/) - but haven't managed to get it working.  Whenever I press the "next" button I get the following js error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'pagination' of undefined
```

My Django project is called "DoSomething" - and it contains a single app called "core".

I have followed all of the instructions to install Dajaxice here: https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/wiki/installation

I have an python file in the "core" directory called "ajax.py" which contains the following code:

```
from views import get_pagination_page
from dajax.core.Dajax import Dajax
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from django.utils import simplejson

@dajaxice_register
def pagination(request, p):
    try:
        page = int(p)
    except:
        page = 1
    items = get_pagination_page(page)
    render = render_to_string('posts_paginator.html', { 'items': items })

    dajax = Dajax()
    dajax.assign('#pagination','innerHTML',render)
    return dajax.json()
```

My views.py file contains the following method:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('id').reverse()
    items = get_pagination_page(1)
    return render_to_response('index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def get_pagination_page(page=1):
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage
    from django.template.loader import render_to_string
    items = Post.objects.order_by('id').reverse()
    paginator = Paginator(items, 10)
    try:
        page = int(page)
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return items
```

My index template contains the following:

```
<div id="pagination">
    {% include "posts_paginator.html" %}
</div>
```

My posts_paginator.html template contains the following link, to trigger the pagination method:

```
{% for i in items.object_list %}
    {{ i }}<br>
{% endfor %}
{% if items.has_next %}
    <a href="#" onclick="Dajaxice.core.pagination(Dajax.process,{'p':{{ items.next_page_number }}})">next</a>
{% endif %}
```

My question is, **within the onClick value, how should I be referencing the pagination method (from my ajax.py file)**.  I can't find anything to explain this - and I've tried every combination of project name/app name that I can think of!

THANKS! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in my case I have to append the Project name as well as the app_label.

```
Dajaxice.MyProject.core.my_dajax_method(Dajax.process, {'form' : data});
```

Comment: ATTENTION: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26219391/dajax-not-working/29230482#29230482